# Add "Request new Password" link to user logIn page

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am using the [Logintoboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module to redirect users to the login page when they try to visit a page for which they don't have the permission to visit.

How do I add a *Request new Password* or *Forgot Password?* link to this page?

Answer (score 0):

This should be already there as a link.
if it is a custom login page, you can add a link with "/user/password" href